# Grab keys from an ordinary USB keyboard

Tags: usb, atmega328, datalogging, keyboard

**Arduino USB**

I want to write an Arduino Sketch (if there is no other possibility it can also be plain c) , to grab keyboard inputs from my ordinary USB keyboard. Preferably without expensive hardware, but as mentioned, if there is no other possibility, this will do it too.

Is this possible with [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html)? I looked a their website, but it seems like this only supports being slave and to imitate a keyboard.

Comment: The USB host shield is what you want.

Comment: PS2 is a whole lot easier. And most usb-keyboards  tend to also "speak" PS2, but you millage may vary. This way you don't need any USB host shield. See http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PS2Keyboard and  http://pinouts.ru/InputCables/usb_ps2_mouse_pinout.shtml for the pinout.

Comment: @Majenko does it again.  That USB Shield is great.  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoUSBHostShield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you have two options:

As suggested by Majenko, you can use the [Arduino USB Host Shield](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoUSBHostShield):
[image: Picture of USB Host Shield]

Alternatively you could use a PS2 keyboard instead (as suggested by Gerben). Arduino already has a library to handle PS2 keyboards, so the implementation of it would be easy. For reference (and example program)
[playground.arduino.cc/Main/PS2Keyboard](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PS2Keyboard)

If you do not have access to a PS2 keyboard or just want to use a USB keyboard, Gerben further suggests that most USB keyboards can be converted to PS2 keyboards with an adapter:
[image: USB to PS2 adapter]

The keyboard must be able to support both formats (USB & PS2).

The following webpage shows the connections needed to go from USB to PS2:  [USB to PS/2 adapter pinout](http://pinouts.ru/InputCables/usb_ps2_mouse_pinout.shtml)

[image: Pinout connection]

Comment: Gerben & Majenko, let me know if you would like to post your own answer and I will remove your content from my answer. Otherwise thank you for your suggestions in the comments and I hope I have done your suggestions justice.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to use this library: https://github.com/techpaul/PS2KeyAdvanced and USB's data +/- connected to pins 2+3 of an arduino to read keys on standard keyboards.

```
keyboard.begin( 3, 2); // D3= data+, D2= data-
```

A standard keyboard is one which doesn't need a driver to work on any computer. I'd tried several libraries, serial keyboard adapters, and ps2/usb converters, and this method works best. Since the ps2-USB converter is just a physical pin change with no logic, standard USB keyboards just magically with with the PS2 libraries; even caps lock and what not...